# Intersection Observer for highlighting nav li

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, intersection-observer

Recently I am developing a simple one page website with 3 sections and I try to use Intersection Observer API to implement a function that allows me to scroll to a part of section and the correct li/link get highlighted on the nav, so for example if I scroll to about section, the about li/link on the nav gets highlighted and others don't.

Is it doable using the Intersection Observer API cause my sections are all have different heights?

**This is what I have now:**

*HTML*

```
<body>
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li class="li-one">One</li>
            <li class="li-two">Two</li>
            <li class="li-three">Three</li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="hero"></div>
        <section class="section-one" data-li="li-one">
            <h1>Section One</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="section-two" data-li="li-two">
            <h1>Section Two</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="section-three" data-li="li-three">
            <h1>Section Three</h1>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

*CSS*

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height:70px;
}

header ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;;
}

header ul li{
    padding: 2rem;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.active{
    color: orange;
}

.hero{
    height: 100vh;
    border: 4px solid red;
}

.section-one{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:250px;
    border: 4px solid purple;
}

.section-two{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:550px;
    border: 4px solid green;
}

.section-three{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:1050px;
    border: 4px solid orange;
}
```

*Javascript*

```
const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('section')];

const observerOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.2,
}


const sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
       
        const getLiClass = entry.target.getAttribute('data-li');
        const getLiElement = document.querySelector(`.${getLiClass}`);
        if(window.innerHeight >= entry.intersectionRect.top / 2 && entry.isIntersecting){
            getLiElement.classList.add('active');
        }else{
            getLiElement.classList.remove('active');
        }
       
    });
}, observerOptions);



sections.forEach((section) => {
    sectionObserver.observe(section);
});
```

I have tried different approaches using the intersection observer API and above approaches is my latest but as you can see it doesn't highlights li/link on the nav one at a time, I also tried an approach that it highlights one at a time but problem with that approach is if I didn't fully scroll out of a section and just scroll back the highlights li/link on the nav doesn't respond(for example, scroll past section one to section two(but section one is still in view), the section two li/link gets highlighted and I scroll back to the section one the section one li/link on the nav is not highlighted but section two li/link still highlighted).

Is it doable using the intersection observer API with sections that have different heights?
(The reason I use intersection observer API is because I did some researches and it seems to have better performance compare to using window.addEventListener('scroll',callback).